# What is the AngularJS equivalent to Backbone's Collections?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js-collections, angular-resource, extjs-stores

Is there an equivalent to [Backbone's Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) or [Ext JS's Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) in Angular JS?  I'm learning about [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), but not quite getting this aspect.

### Controller

```
// This is the "collection" I'm interested in.
$scope.foos = [];

// Foo is a $resource.
Foo.query(function (foos) {

  // This works, but is there a smarter "collection" object?
  $scope.foos = foos;
});

$scope.createFoo = function (data) {
  var foo = new Foo(data);

  foo.$save(function (shinyNewFoo) {
    $scope.foos.unshift(shinyNewFoo);
  });
};
```

### Explanation

In `$scope.createFoo` I'm making a new Foo, persisting it, then adding it to my *poor man's collection*, an array.  This works and the view is updated correctly, but I'm too lazy for this.  Ideally, I'd like to have a "collection" I can add to and remove from that will automatically POST/DELETE.  Maybe something like the following.

### Pretend Implementation

```
$scope.fooCollection = new CoolCollection({
  // specify the type of resources this collection will contain
  itemsResource: Foo
});

// Creates new Foo, saves, adds to collection.
$scope.fooCollection.add(data);
```

Does something like this exist?  The $resource docs mention a collection, but I didn't really get it.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762574/backbone-style-models-in-angularjs) seemed promising, but didn't explain the collection idea.  Am I missing something or just not thinking about this *the Angular way*?

---

## Addendum

In the MEAN.io boilerplate, [the article controller](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/public/js/controllers/articles.js) suggests that the "collection" is managed manually (see the `splice` below).

```
$scope.remove = function(article) {
    if (article) {
        article.$remove();

        for (var i in $scope.articles) {
            if ($scope.articles[i] === article) {
                $scope.articles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $scope.article.$remove();
        $location.path('articles');
    }
};
```

If this elusive "collection" existed, I suppose they would have used it.  Instead, they're managing an array manually.

Comment: Why? An advantage of Angular is that you can work with POJOs

Comment: Does something like this exist? no, angular has no models nor collections.I suggest you finish the tutorial in the docs before asking more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @mpm.  I've done the tutorial and read all of the Developer Guide and it wasn't clear.  That's why I asked.

Comment: nothing prevents you from using backbone models and collections inside angular services. Having a true model layer is important. Sending random hashs back to the server is not a best practice. However you'd need (in my opinion) to override backbone sync with angularjs ajax apis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS does not define any kind of structured data model. This part is entirely up to you.

The $resource service is just a wrapper on top of the lower-level $http service; it defines a high level way to *fetch* your data from the server and has little to do with how you *structure* your data on the frontend.

If a more sophisticated frontend data model is required by your application, you should investigate other JS libraries or roll your own. However, angular's singleton services and powerful two-way data binding make this unnecessary for most small/medium applications.